# Split a Unicode string maintaining uppercase characters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I want to split a string according to a predefined set of substrings (lowercase), though the actual text can contain uppercase characters anyplace. The task is to find the matches, longer preferred over shorter (like `"tt"` over `"t"` hence the order of `alt`) **and** to maintain upper/lowercase status. Since `StringCases` has a quirk not being able to correctly recognize some upper/lowercase characters (cf. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3577/89)), the solution is not trivial.

The following code matches every element in `alt` correctly, though it also converts everything to lowercase:

```
alt = "tt" | "t" | "a" | "á";
word = "TtattÁatT";
StringCases[ToLowerCase@word, alt]
```

> `{"tt", "a", "tt", "á", "a", "tt"}`

The next one, while correctly maintains capital letters, fails to recognize `"Á"` as the uppercase version of `"á"` (or of `a`, see later).

```
StringCases[word, alt, IgnoreCase -> True]
```

> `{"Tt", "a", "tt", "a", "tT"}`

The problem here is that `StringMatchQ` returns `False`:

```
StringMatchQ["A", "a", IgnoreCase -> True]       (* ==> True *)
StringMatchQ["Á", "á", IgnoreCase -> True]       (* ==> False *)
StringMatchQ["Á", "a", IgnoreCase -> True]       (* ==> False *)
StringMatchQ["Á", "á" | "a", IgnoreCase -> True] (* ==> True *)
(* for the record *)
ToLowerCase@"Á" === "á"       (* ==> True *)
ToUpperCase@"á" === "Á"       (* ==> True *)
```

I think it actually is a bug, as this behaviour is rather inconsistent. Nevertheless, the next code I came up with to match `"Á"` fails:

```
StringCases[word, __?(StringMatchQ[#, alt, IgnoreCase -> True] &), IgnoreCase -> True]
```

> `{"Ttatt", "atT"}`

It cannot recognize `"Á"`, and it splits by the longest match instead of exact matches.

Is it possible to overcome somehow this issue *without* explicitly listing all combinations of upper/lowercase letters (like `"a"|"A"|"á"|"Á"|"tt"|"tT"|"Tt"|...`) or saving and restoring character states (upper/lowercase) manually? There are [nice examples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3455/89) how the string patternmatcher can be used effectively, I hope this can be solved as well.

**Question**

Given a possibly large list of short elementary strings like `"tt" | "t" | "a" | "á"`, how can a larger string be split into elementary substrings with keeping all uppercase letters correctly. For example:

```
"TtattÁatT" == > {"Tt", "a", "tt", "Á", "a", "tT"}
```

Comment: Can anyone comfirm/explain the bug-like behaviour reported above?

Comment: This may be related to problems reported in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/unicode-aware-string-functions/), and duscussed also in comments below it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the lower case conversion as a condition on the pattern, and thereby retain the original:

```
StringCases["TtattÁatT", c__ /; MemberQ[List@@alt, ToLowerCase[c]]]
```

> `{"Tt", "a", "tt", "Á", "a", "tT"}`

Comment: Ingenious! Though I wonder, why these two give different results: `StringCases["TtattÁatT", c__ /; MemberQ[List @@ alt, ToLowerCase[c]]]` and `StringCases["TtattÁatT", __?(MemberQ[List @@ alt, ToLowerCase[#]] &)]`

Comment: For a `StringExpression` the `?` test works character by character rather than on the string as a whole.

Comment: @Istvan Probably because `PatternTest` tests each entry in the sequence individually, while `Condition` applies to the entire sequence / substring (I did not test, but this is what I'd think).

Answer (score 9):

Here is an alternative which might be somewhat faster on large strings:

```
StringTake[word, StringPosition[ToLowerCase@word, alt, Overlaps -> None]]
```

> `{"Tt", "a", "tt", "Á", "a", "tT"}`