# How do I reassign canonical ordering of special expressions?

Tags: output-formatting, sorting

### 1. Default behavior of Sort

Note: this peculiarity is described in a comment to a [related question at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111778/overriding-the-default-display-order-of-orderless-functions) but I think it's worth restating here at mma.sx.

It is estabilished in documentation that `Sort` uses `OrderedQ` by default:

> `Sort[list, p]` applies the function `p` to pairs of elements in list to
>   determine whether they are in order. The default function `p` is
>   `OrderedQ[{#1, #2}]&`.

However, modification of `OrderedQ` doesn't really change the default behavior of Sort:

```
Unprotect@OrderedQ;
OrderedQ[{special2, special1}, ___] := True; 
OrderedQ[{special1, special2}, ___] := False;
Protect@OrderedQ;

Sort@{special2, special1}
{special1, special2}
```

unless you explicitly mention that it should be default:

```
Sort[{special2, special1}, OrderedQ@{#1, #2}&]
{special2, special1}
```

### 2. Is specifying global custom sorting rules possible?

Suppose I have `InitialObject@"X"` and `FinalObject@"Y"`, and I want to always put `InitialObject` before `FinalObject`. Lots of Mathematica's internal functions would be affected then, I guess, but I still think it's fairly legit to add special ordering rules for special expressions, especially if they are properly kept in packages. Is it possible to specify ordering rules for expressions, say, of the form `InitialObject@___` and `FinalObject@___`, similar to

```
OrderedQ[{_InitialObject, _FinalObject}, ___] := True
OrderedQ[{_FinalObject, _InitialObject}, ___] := False
```

so that they are automatically applied inside `Plus`, `Times`, when `Union` is called, etc.? So far I tried what is described in 1. Tried redefining `Order` as well, to no effect. (Version 8)

My research of StackExchange archives suggests it's not possible but I still hold some hope. I think I'd use whatever dirty hack offered.

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31261/is-there-a-precedence-table-for-the-canonical-sort-ordering

Comment: If this is for display purposes using `Block[{$Post = myOrder},...]` in your package might help.

Comment: “I think I'd use whatever dirty hack offered.” — 
Or maybe not. It would probably affect pattern matching in definitions, e.g. of the form `f@g@x___` where `g` is `Orderless`.