# How to correctly sort string list based on numeric substring pattern?

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm having a hard time sorting a big list of filenames. I've tried a bunch of things, and tried to adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31261/is-there-a-precedence-table-for-the-canonical-sort-ordering) but seemed over-killing(?)...

```
(*My list of filenames*)
dummyList = {"gibberish_A1p1_B0p1.mx", "gibberish_A11p11_B0p.mx","gibberish_A0p1_B0p2.mx"};
```

Suppose I have a string list like the one below. It is a list of filenames. Each name indicates the values of two parameters, `A` and `B`, in this format: if A was 0.0, then the name contains the substring `0p` (the `p` just means 'period'), if it was 1.1, then the substring would be `1p1` and so forth (so you can guess the same goes for `B`).

Anyways, suppose I want to order the list, so that the files are ordered by the value of either `A` or `B`.

So, let's say I want to order them by `A`, then I'd like to get:

```
(*Correct sorting*)
{"gibberish_A0p1_B0p2.mx", "gibberish_A1p1_B0p1.mx", "gibberish_A11p11_B0p.mx"}
```

But instead I kept getting something like this:

```
AlphabeticSort[dummyList]
{"gibberish_A0p1_B0p2.mx", "gibberish_A11p11_B0p.mx", "gibberish_A1p1_B0p1.mx"}
```

Now, these are simple cases. In my actual application, I'd like to do the proper sorting for either `A`, `B`, or something else (say `C`), and the `gibberish` is some other complicated substring.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use [SortBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html).

We need a function that extracts the numeric values in your string. Here is one solution:

```
pvalue[xpy_]:=ToExpression[StringReplace[xpy,"p"->"."]];
abcvalue[ABC_][filename_]:=pvalue[First[StringSplit[Last[StringSplit[filename,"_"<>ABC]],"_"|"."]]];
```

To see how they work, try

```
pvalue["54p432"]
(* 54.432 *)

abcvalue["A"]["gibberish_A0p1_B0p2.mx"]
(* 0.1 *)

abcvalue["B"]["gibberish_A0p1_B0p2.mx"]
(* 0.2 *)
```

**Warning.** The function `abcvalue` assumes that `gibberish` does not contain `_A` as a substring and so on. If it does, then one will have to make `abcvalue` slightly more selective.

In any case, now you'd simply do this:

```
SortBy[dummyList,abcvalue["A"]]
SortBy[dummyList,abcvalue["B"]]
```

Comment: Cool, this really helped me getting started, just had to adjust for the shenanigans in `gibberish`.