# Strange behavior of MinimalBy

Tags: core-language, numerical-value

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};  
MinimalBy[data, Norm@# &]  
Output: {{2, 2}}
```

When applying numerically :

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};  
MinimalBy[data, N@Norm@# &]  
Output: {{1, 2}}
```

Comment: Notice that, as mentioned in **Details** section of document of `MinimalBy`: Values of $f[e_i]$ are compared using the same canonical order as in `Sort`.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78183/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31261/1871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TakeSmallestBy` gives the correct solution automatically

```
TakeSmallestBy[data, Norm, 1]
```

{{1, 2}}

A hash-free `MinimalBy` solution

```
MinimalBy[data, N @* Norm]
```

{{1, 2}}

Documentation Details of `TakeSmallestBy`

*"TakeSmallestBy sorts ... by numerical magnitude."*

Documentation Details of `MinimalBy`

*"Values ... are compared using the same canonical order as in  Sort."*

```
Norm /@ data // Sort
```

{2 * Sqrt[2], 3 * Sqrt[2], Sqrt[5]}

```
N[%]
```

{2.82843, 4.24264, 2.23607}

Answer (score 4):

`Norm` doesn't give the correct answer (see @Nasser's answer).

workaround

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
MinimalBy[data, ( # . # &)]
(*{{1, 2}}*)
```