# How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

The following examples only work for the first character of the whole string, but not of words.

```
s = "words are lowercase";
StringJoin[MapAt[ToUpperCase, Characters[s], 1]]   (* ==> "Words are lowercase" *)
StringReplacePart[#, ToUpperCase[StringTake[#, 1]], 1]&@s  (* ==> "Words are lowercase" *)
```

Is there any method along these lines to produce correct **title case** strings of the form:

```
"Words Are Lowercase"
```

Comment: See the first example in [`WordBoundary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WordBoundary.html).

Comment: @Kuba ah, of course, there are many many words to capitalize.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I think of one example in Help page.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, I think you can add this as one answer, maybe the simplest one. And also others may have many other answers.

Comment: To the close-voters, how exactly is this ***easily found in the documentation***?  What did you search by, or by which path did you navigate to this example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks, I don't think it's so easy, even I've used WordBoudary before.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On the surface, I agree with Michael, it is a [documentation example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WordBoundary.html), and it is findable via the details section of [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html). That said, Istvan showed it isn't quite that simple.

Comment: I didn't think it should be closed, but I looked up "WordBoundary" just to check on using it to make up an answer.  However, if you search for "capitalize", `WordBoundary` is the second hit in V9.  But see István's answer - those sorts of unexpected complications are reasons such questions should not be closed, at least not right away.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree with that assessment, the doc example was _easy_ to find (at least for me). Yet, it fails for a more complete character set, so further examples are needed.

Comment: Working on your BibTeX database?

Comment: Also there is a dynamic manipulate example in documentation about this. I cann't find it now...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Apparently the search has been improved since v7.

Comment: @YvesKlett not that, one usage is to find all single meaningful words in such unicode form characters like "\\[Alpha]"

Comment: Note most of the solutions posted to date make the assumption the input will be lowercase. You can wrap your input in [`ToLowerCase`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToLowerCase.html) to compensate, e.g. if you have all-caps input.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WordBoundary.html), though IMHO not easy to find:

```
StringReplace["this is a test", WordBoundary ~~ x_ :> ToUpperCase[x]]
```

> ```
> "This Is A Test"
> ```

---

István Zachar highlighted a problem with `WordBoundary` that I'm still trying to understand.  Nevertheless it seems that one can use:

```
strAcc = "árv ízt űr őt ük örf úr óg ép";

StringReplace[strAcc, z : (StartOfString | WhitespaceCharacter ~~ _) :> ToUpperCase[z]]
```

> ```
> "Árv Ízt Űr Őt Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"
> ```

It appears that the [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE) library at least as used by *Mathematica* does not recognize certain characters as letters.  A few examples:

```
StringReplace[strAcc, z : RegularExpression["(?:\\A|\\s)."] :> ToUpperCase[z]]
StringReplace[strAcc, z : RegularExpression["\\b."] :> ToUpperCase[z]]
```

> ```
> "Árv Ízt Űr Őt Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"
>
> "Árv Ízt űR őT Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"  (* note odd handling *)
> ```

```
StringCases["abcőű", RegularExpression["\\w"]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c"}                  (* ő and ű missing *)
> ```

Comment: Actually, `LetterQ /@ Characters@"áéíóöőüű"` returns all `True`, so it is only `LetterCharacter` that does not consider them letters...

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thank you.  I'm guessing this has something to do with compilation to [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE).  Do you happen to know if Perl considers these to be letters?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about Perl.

Comment: This isn't a separate answer, but it's worth knowing that "Title case" usually does not capitalize certain small words, so you'd do something like: `replacelittlewords = 
 z : (StartOfString | WhitespaceCharacter ~~ # ~~ 
       WhitespaceCharacter) :> ToLowerCase[z] & /@ {"A", "An", "The", 
   "Is", "On", "To"}` and then `StringReplace[
 StringReplace["This is a test about which you will be amazed", 
  z : (StartOfString | WhitespaceCharacter ~~ _) :> 
   ToUpperCase[z]], replacelittlewords]`.

Comment: Note that at least in version 11.3 `RegularExpression["\\b."]` correctly recognizes "ű" and "ő" as letters (but in version 8.0.4 it doesn't).

Comment: @Alexey thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Actually, `WordBoundary` won't always work correctly (see [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3813/89)):

```
str = "the lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox.";
strAcc = "árv ízt űr őt ük örf úr óg ép";

StringReplace[str, WordBoundary ~~ x_ :> ToUpperCase[x]]
StringReplace[strAcc, WordBoundary ~~ x_ :> ToUpperCase[x]]
```

> ```
> "The Lazy Dog Jumped Over The Quick Brown Fox."
>
> "Árv Ízt űR őT Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"   (* note ű,ő instead of Ű,Ő *)
> ```

Use instead this custom made `toTitleCase`:

```
toTitleCase[str__] := StringJoin@Riffle[ToUpperCase@StringTake[#, 1] <> 
       ToLowerCase@StringTake[#, {2, -1}] & /@ StringSplit@StringJoin@str, " "];

toTitleCase[str]
toTitleCase[strAcc]
```

> ```
> "The Lazy Dog Jumped On The Quick Brown Fox."
>
> "Árv Ízt Űr Őt Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"
> ```

---

In **version 10.1**, this is built in as `ToTitleCase` (if I recall correctly, it was an experimental function; documentation is no longer accessible on the net). This version **removes all non-alphanumeric characters** from the string; I assume this is a bug.

```
ToTitleCase[str]
ToTitleCase[strAcc]
```

> ```
> "The Lazy Dog Jumped On The Quick Brown Fox"
>
> "Árv Ízt Űr Őt Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"
> ```

---

`ToTitleCase` has an eventful development history: in **version 11**, it is removed from among the built-ins, but is still acccessible from the `` "GeneralUtilities`" `` context. It does not remove non-alphanumeric characters anymore from the string.

```
GeneralUtilities`ToTitleCase[str]
GeneralUtilities`ToTitleCase[strAcc]
```

> ```
> "The Lazy Dog Jumped Over the Quick Brown Fox."
>
> "Árv Ízt Űr Őt Ük Örf Úr Óg Ép"
> ```

Comment: Jumped *on* the fox?  We learned it as *over*. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, obviously there were other messages sent over the Moscow-Budapest hotline... If you examine it more closely, there are further discrepancies :) (simple explanation: my memory failed me)

Comment: Do you understand why `ű` is not considered a `LetterCharacter`?

Comment: The function `ToTitleCase` doesn't seem to exist anymore (v11).

Comment: @becko Thanks for pointing it out! Actually it does exist, but in `GeneralUtilities`; please see edit.

Answer (score 6):

While I endorse Mr.Wizard's pattern matching solution and I've given Istvàn +1 I would also like to submit this function which is meant to not rely on string patterns and be as readable as possible:

```
toTitleCase[str_] := StringJoin[
  MapAt[
   ToUpperCase, Characters[str], 
   Position[Characters[" " <> StringTrim@str], " "]
   ]
  ]

toTitleCase["the lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox"]
```

> "The Lazy Dog Jumped Over The Quick Brown Fox"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't endorse this.  `MapAt` has poor algorithmic complexity, so you are shifting an operation out of an optimized domain into a known inefficient one. You have also introduced a bug in the case that there is a trailing space on the string.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fair enough, I didn't think about it in terms of speed especially with the sample being so tiny. :/ Fixed the problem with the trailing space though.

Answer (score 4):

Starting in M11.2 or M11.3 you can use [`Capitalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Capitalize) with "TitleCase" as the second argument:

```
Capitalize["words are lowercase", "TitleCase"]
```

> "Words Are Lowercase"

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this problem with strings containing parentheses and acronyms, and the above solutions didn't work correctly for me. This is the solution I came up with:

```
toTitleCase[str_] := StringReplace[
    ToUpperCase@str, (f_?LetterQ ~~ rest:(LetterCharacter..)) :> 
    f <> ToLowerCase[rest]
];

toTitleCase["the (LAZY) d.O.G."]
```

> "The (Lazy) D.O.G."

Answer (score 1):

```
rule = RegularExpression["\\b([[:lower:]])"] :> ToUpperCase["$1"];
StringReplace[s, rule]
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that your code works correctly in version 11.3, but not in version 8.0.4. (+1)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Then what would be wrong in Version 8.0.4?

Comment: It doesn't recognize "ű" and "ő" as letters, see the answer by Mr.Wizard: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32045/280

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Might `"[[:lower:]]"` have a narrower scope in that version?

Comment: `\\b` certainly has narrower scope.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Well; actually I can only take one version into my consideration. Anyway, thx for the information!

Comment: Just have checked: `"[[:lower:]]"` also doesn't recognize  "ű" and "ő" in version 8.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers posted has a wrong result when applied to this string :

"hoSsEiN HAdi" -> "HoSsEiN HAdi"

But you can use the below code to ensure that all of the subsequent letters has been changed to LowerCase:

```
StringJoin @ StringCases["aA AA aa Aa 1a 2a a2 A2", WordBoundary~~Shortest[x_] ~~ Shortest[y___] ~~ WordBoundary :> ToUpperCase[x] <> ToLowerCase[y]]
```

This gives the following result :

```
"Aa Aa Aa Aa 1a 2a A2 A2"
```