# Error with String patterns producing Removed["$$Failure"]

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, version-7

While working on [How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32043/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string) and trying to understand why certain characters were not considered letters I tried this:

```
StringCases["áéíóöőüű", _?LetterQ]
```

> ```
> LetterQ::string: String expected at position 1 in LetterQ[Removed[$$Failure]]. >>
>
> LetterQ::string: String expected at position 1 in LetterQ[Removed[$$Failure]]. >>
>
> LetterQ::string: String expected at position 1 in LetterQ[Removed[$$Failure]]. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of LetterQ::string will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> {}
> ```

I then tried a `Print` function to see what was going on:

```
StringCases["áéíóöőüű", _?Print];
```

> ```
> á  
> é  
> í  
> ó  
> ö  
> ő  
> ü  
> ű
> ```

No errors.  Then I tried a function that Prints, but returns `True`:

```
StringCases["áéíóöőüű", _?((Print["(", FullForm@#, ")"]; True) &)]
```

This produced interleaved lines of characters (expected) and `Removed[$$Failure]` (not expected).  I can't include the output properly because of [this StackExchange bug](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529/121).

- What is the cause of this?
- Has it been fixed since version 7?

Comment: Does not happen for me (v8.0.4 Linux64). `StringCases["áéíóöőüű", _?LetterQ] == Characters["áéíóöőüű"]`

Comment: I get the same message for MMA 7.0 on mac OSX, but in version 9.0.0 it works fine.

Comment: There is no explicit `Removed[$$Failure]` at all under Win7, v9.0.1.

Comment: No problems in either 8 or 9 (Win7-64). BTW I remember researching related matters. See my comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/unicode-aware-string-functions).